# Reducing by one recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I am currently working on a school assignment to generate the first 25 prime numbers using recursion. While the program I have written generates the prime numbers, an error occurs after the 23rd number.

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

I have fixed this issue by extending the recursion depth on my own computer, however I realize that not everyone will have done the same. I have determined that I will instead shorten the amount of recursions running in the program. I am having trouble with this and would like to ask for help.

First.

```
def checkPrime(a, n, c):
```

Where a is the divisor, n is the possible prime, and c is the iteration.

```
if c <= 24:
 if n % a <= 0:
  if n == a:
    print(n, end = ' ')
    return checkPrime(2, n + 1, c + 1)
  return checkPrime(2, n + 1, c)
return checkPrime(a + 1, n, c)
```

It basically checks the iteration, whether n is divisible by a, and if n is equal to the a. If n isn't divisible by a it recurs with a plus one. If n isn't equal to a it recurs with the next possible prime and resets the divisor to 2. If everything is True it prints the prime and recurs with the next possible prime, resets the divisor to 2, and add one to the counter.

I call the function like this:

```
checkPrime(2, 2, 0)
```

Two is the starting divisor and possible prime number and 0 is the iteration.

What I would like to do is be able to get rid of one of the recursions. I do not want to be told the exact line code I would need to use. If you would just point me in the right direction I would very much appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: This is only a workaround, but you can extend the recursion depth in your Python code, i.e. `sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)`.

Comment: One quick note - if you assume 2 is prime by default and start from 3, then you can count up by 2 instead of by 1, which runs twice as quickly

Comment: @Selcuk I am adamant on finding a way to reduce the recursions instead, thank you anyways. Green Cloak Guy I was thinking of that, however the whole point of the assignment is to find the prime numbers using the program, including two. If there was a way to do this while still using the program to clarify that two is prime I would be elated.

Comment: Are you forbidden to use *any* looping?  Are you restricted to one divisor check per call?

Comment: The innate problem with this organization is that *every* division check requires a new recursion, so you're limited to 1000 division checks total.  Unless there is a way you're allowed to backtrack, returning a result, so that you don't nest *every* check, you're stuck.  What are the project restrictions in this regard?

Comment: You can reduce the quantity of calls by shortening your candidate divisors.  This doesn't remove a recursion, but will get you to 25 primes.  (1) Check only existing primes; this requires maintaining a list of found primes; (2) Check only up through the sqrt of the possible prime; if you haven't found a divisor by then, then the number is prime.

Comment: Can you use the `any` and `all` functions?  This would allow you to check all possible divisors in a single statement, rather than recurring for each divisor.

Comment: No looping, program has to find primes no helping it. However, @Prune the any and all functions will work in my scenario. I thank you dearly for the help and bid you adu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're allowed `any` and `all`, then your critical test is to see whether you have any valid divisor of the candidate number:

```
limit = ceil(sqrt(cand+1))
if not any([cand % divisor == 0 for divisor in range(2, limit)]):
    # This is a prime
```

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much. I would like to understand more about the any and all methods though if it doesn't trouble you. I think I know what they do, but I'm not sure. any is true for any iterations that are are true and all only if all iterations are true?